# Is it possible to add a loop-cut like bar to a wireframe-like object?

Tags: modeling

I wanted to create an electric fan grill. After making the shape in the screenshot below (circle -> select circumference -> extrude -> scale -> wireframe), I found that my fan has one more concentric circle. I tried to add a loop cut, but it did not work. After several seconds of vain attempt, I realised that the object is not a flat surface and edges, but it is a wireframe. I wonder if there is a way to add a loop cut to a solid object.

I know I can undo the wireframe modifier and add a loop cut and then apply wireframe again, but just in case the solid object is not created by the wireframe modifier.

[image]

Comment: You can use the knife tool in orthographic mode, then press "f" to add a face then delete "only faces", but it will mess up your topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop cuts can only be added to face loops. If you've applied the wireframe modifier, you essentially turned each edge into a mesh, so you won't be able to add a concentric loop cut to this object.